# Given $L(y) = \int_ {1}^{y}\frac{1}{t}dy$ , $y\in(0, \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-functions

I am proving Theorem 37.4 , Elementary Analysis, Kenneth Ross.

Stating $$L(y) = \int_{1}^{y}\frac{1}{t}\operatorname{d}t,\quad y\in(0,\infty)$$

I have to prove that

(i) the function L is strictly increasing , continuous and differentiable in $(0,\infty)$

(ii) $L(yz)= L(y)+L(z)$, for $ y, z \in (0,\infty)$ .

For(i): Since the function $\frac{1}{t}$ is continuous in the open interval$(0,\infty)$ that contains the point 1.Then the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus ensures that $L(y) = \int_{1}^{y}\frac{1}{t}dt $ is differentiable on the interval $(0,\infty)$ and hence also continuous there.

For the part (ii)  the book states that consider for any fixed z, $ g(y)= L(yz) - L(y) - L(z).$ Then using the fundamental theorem of calculus  we have

$g'(y)=\frac{1}{yz}\frac{d(yz)}{dy}$ $- \frac{1}{y} - 0 = 0 $ , for any $ y\in (0,\infty).$

Then, again by the fundamental theorem again, we have

$\int_{1}^{y} g'(t) dt  = g(y) - g(1)$, since $ g(1) = L(z) - L(1)- L(z)$ and $ L(1)= 0 $

This implies that $g(y)=0$.

Also, have to show (iii) $lim y\rightarrow\infty L(y)= +\infty$

**The proof in the book says : Since, $L(2) >0 $ , then $L(2^n) = n L(2)  >0 $
Then as L is a strictly increasing function then 
$ Lim y\rightarrow \infty L(y) = Lim n \rightarrow\infty L(2^n)= \infty$

Please suggest what could be the steps.

I am thinking if we take y to be sufficiently large, then there exists a natural number n such that $ y > 2^n$ , then $ L(y) >  L( 2^n)$.

How to ensure that if y approaches infinity then n also approaches infinity.**

Comment: Your notation is confusing and, really, wrong.  Integrate over something beside $y$, say, $t$.

Comment: @RonGordon: I presume you meant 'besides $y$'..

Comment: @copper.hat: my fingers and mind had a disagreement, apparently.

Comment: Vert syrange...

Comment: @RonGordon: Thanks..I made a mistake.

Comment: For the first part you need to note that you are integrating a positive function and use that to show that the integral is increasing - since you have not mentioned this in your suggested answer. And to show this for the whole positive real line, pick an arbitrary point and show that it is true there.

Comment: Halfway there, pal.

Comment: The first and the second term appear because you need to use the fundamental theorem of calculus for differentiating an integral. Basically you evaluate the integrand at the endpoints...

Comment: And forgot to mention, you also multiply by the derivative with respect to $y$ of the upper bound function, in your case this is $f(y)= zy$ so you get the $z$ in the numerator. It's basically chain rule.

Comment: @chango: thanks a lot ! i got it now.

Comment: @chango: can you please help with first part too.

Comment: you basically have it. the FTC tells you that your function is differentiable (and therefore continuous) at all $x \in (0,\infty)$. The increasing bit you get (as mentioned by Mark) by noting that the integral of a positive function over an interval gives you a positive number. Let $z > y$ be two numbers in $(0,\infty)$. Then $L(z) - L(y) =  \int_y^z \frac{1}{t} dt > 0$

Comment: @chango: many thanks. I also have a doubt that does the fundamental theorem here ensure continuity in (0, infinity)

Comment: yes it does. it ensures differentiability which is stronger.

Comment: @chango: thanks once again..i have now edited the question. kindly help if it is Ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show part three you have to prove that $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t}$ is unbounded.
This should be easy if you altready know few basic resuts about convergent and divergent series.

Note that $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \int_n^{n+1}\frac{dt}{t} \ge \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \int_n^{n+1}\frac{dt}{n+1}$. This last inequality follows from the fact that $\frac{1}{n} \ge \frac{1}{t} \ge \frac{1}{n+1}$, $t \in [n,n+1]$.

$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \int_n^{n+1}\frac{dt}{n+1} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}\int_{n}^{n+1}dt = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1} = \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n} = \infty$.

Therefore $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t} \ge \infty \Longrightarrow \int_1^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t} = \infty$.

For the divergence of the harmonic series you can give a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)

Comment: $n$ starts at $2$ in the last sum...

Comment: @user67133: thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @user67133: I need your help in proving the proof in the book. i have edited my question please see my doubt in bold.

Answer (score 1):

One more time: $\frac{1}{n} \ge \frac{1}{t} \ge \frac{1}{n+1}$, $t \in [n,n+1]$, therefore $L(2) = \int_1^2\frac{dt}{t} \ge \frac{1}{2}\int_1^2dt = \frac{1}{2} > 0$.

$L(2^n) = L(2 \cdot 2^{n-1}) = L(2) + L(2^{n-1})$ using the property we have already proved. Iteraring the argument we obtain $L(2^n) = L(2) + \dots + L(2) = nL(2)$.

It is also clear that $L(2^n) \le L(y)$ when $2^n \le y$, therefore $L(2^n) \le \lim_{y \to \infty} L(y)$ **holds for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$**. If it holds for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ you are allowed to consider $n$ as big as you like it. 
This gives:

$\lim_{y \to \infty}L(y) \ge \lim_{n \to \infty}L(2^n) = \lim_{n \to \infty}nL(2) \ge \lim_{n \to \infty}n \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \infty$.

The trick is to consider the limit over $y$ before taking the limit over $n$. This is how you are allowed to take $n$ as big as you wish being sure that $y$ is still bigger.

I hope everything's clear now! :D

Comment: Many thanks for the insightful answers. Just one more doubt which i request you to explain. After you got $L(2^n)<L(y)$ how is it possible to take limits as y goes infinity and keep n as fixed as we are.

Comment: Just doing it: if $L(2^n) < L(y)$ it is also true that $L(2^n) < L(y + 1) < L(y + 2) \dots$. This means that you can take bigger and bigger and the inequality is preserved because $L$ is increasing. Another way to do that is to take the limit of both the sides of the inequality. $\lim_y L(2^n) \le \lim_y L(y)$ and $\lim_y L(2^n) = L(2^n)$ because it doesn't depend on $y$. Apllying limitis in different moments, when you are allowed to do so, is a stadard way to prove many results.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it so well :)

Comment: you're wellcome!